# nextLine() and while loop misbehavior in unicode-16

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

**Edit:** This actually turned into quite an interesting problem.  After some help from commenters, I posted a self-answer.  I should mention that my project is in Unicode-16, which looks like it was the source of the trouble.

The problem is that the loop was not exiting as expected, in what appears to be trivially simple code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lambda2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = in.nextLine();
        while (!input.equals("exit")){
            System.out.println("input is \""+ input + "\"");
            System.out.println(input.equals("exit"));

            input = in.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Thank you!");
    }
}
```

## Run 1:

```
exit
Thank you!
```

So far, so good.  But when I enter the loop, I run into trouble:

## Run 2:

```
asdf
input is "asdf"
false
exit
input is "exit"
false
exit
input is "exit"
false
```

Last I checked `"exit".equals("exit")` should return `true`, not `false`.  I've tried using `trim()` on my inputs in case there was some skullduggery with new lines... What in the world am I missing??

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187039/discussion-on-question-by-ben-i-nextline-and-while-loop-misbehavior-in-unicod).

Answer (score 1):

Neither of them posted an answer, but with the help of [GBlodgett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8534008/gblodgett) and [StephenC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c), an interesting answer did eventually emerge.

The problem was that the project is, by necessity, in a UTF encoding, and a [BOM](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark) character (U-FEFF) was being added to the beginning of the user input, making it 5 characters long.

The solution was to remove the BOM character immediately after collection:

`input = input.replace("\uFEFF", "");`

What is still somewhat mysterious, however, is why no BOM was added to the first input, but only to the subsequent ones.  It seems like **Run 1** should not have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it is working fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I hope you've been having a good time here and finding it useful.  You should know that you're breaking a few norms here.  First, it is an image of text, which makes this answer less useful to future visitors.  Second, it's actually a non-answer.  (Being unable to reproduce the problem doesn't constitute an answer.)  (I'm about to post a self-answer, as it turned out to be an interesting UTF BOM issue.)

Comment: Also, don't worry too much, it takes a while to get used to this place. =)